# See any security risks with this approach?

Tags: security, authentication

I'm working on a RESTful(ish) API that has the following authentication style:

- A client calls an "authenticate" API method and passes a username and password over HTTPS POST.  This method returns basic account information and a "client token", which is stored on the user account in the database.
- All further API calls (all over HTTPS POST) require a client token.  If the system can't find the requester by client token, the call is rejected.

My open questions are:
1)  Does anyone see a major security problem with this?
2)  Is there any good reason why I should have client tokens expire over time or change?  Right now I assign a random one to every user.  If the user does a logout or forgot password, I generate a new one.

I'd love to know everyone's thoughts on this approach.  I'm not going for innovation, I'm just making I'm aware of the risks on this approach.

Answer (score 3):

What you've described is functionally equivalent to a session cookie, only reimplemented in  your application, and therefore subject to a number of pitfalls that have likely already been dealt with by most web frameworks.

- Ensure your tokens have enough bits of entropy.  If the tokens are simple 32-bit integers, wild guesses might be enough to hit on one in use by someone else.
- If you're generating these tokens randomly, ensure you use a cryptographically-strong source of random numbers, or the next token might be guessable based on previous tokens.
- If these `POST` requests are coming from scripts and such embedded in web pages, passing the token around as an explicit parameter instead of as a cookie declared `secure` and `httponly` makes token-stealing by cross-site scripts much easier.

Comment: Hi Jeffery - Great suggestions.  The client token is basically made via sha1($user_id . time() . $secret_salt), so it shouldn't be possible to randomly guess one.  The cross-site scripting is a concern.  I'll have to look into the secure cookie - I've never heard of that.  I'll have to investigate whether PhoneGap supports cookies.  Thanks for the tips!

Comment: @Anthony What does a user ID and a ‘secret salt’ look like? Is the latter a fixed value?

Comment: As a side note, using an http header to transfer the token vs a parameter has certain advantages if the application is complex or you end up using the token in a different domain, and mitigates some security issues (e.g. Prevents turning a self xss into a full xss). Also be careful with logs as a parameter is more likely to end up there than headers or cookies